# Checking if the characters in a string are all unique

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this problem using JS by just using an array.

```
var str = 'abcdefgh';

for (i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
  arr[i] = false;
}

function check() {
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (arr[str.charCodeAt(i)] == true) {
      return false;
    }
    arr[str.charCodeAt(i)] = true;
  }
  return true;
}
```

I am initializing an array of fixed size 256 to have the boolean value `false`.
Then i am setting the value for the corresponding ASCII  index to true for characters in the string. And if i find the same character again, i am returning `false`.

While running the program, i am getting false returned even if the string doesn't have any duplicate characters.

Comment: your code seems right, can you post the test case for which it is failing to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use object for faster result

```js
function is_unique(str) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var z = 0; z < str.length; ++z) {
    var ch = str[z];
    if (obj[ch]) return false;
    obj[ch] = true;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(is_unique("abcdefgh")); // true
console.log(is_unique("aa")); // false
```

Answer (score 24):

Fill a `Set` with all characters and compare its size to the string's length:

```js
function isUnique(str) {
  return new Set(str).size == str.length;
}

console.log(isUnique('abc'));    // true
console.log(isUnique('abcabc')); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

use .match() function for each of the character. calculate occurrences using length. Guess thats it.

```
(str.match(/yourChar/g) || []).length
```

Comment: you must sanitize the `yourChar` first.. because it's possible that it contains special regex characters..

Comment: btw, it's missing `(` at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

We can also try using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) method:

```
function stringIsUnique(input) {
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input.indexOf(input[i]) !== input.lastIndexOf(input[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: this is by far the fastest approach

Answer (score 0):

You are using `arr[str.charCodeAt(i)]` which is wrong.
It should be `arr[str[i].charCodeAt(0)]`

```
var arr = [];
var str="abcdefgh";
for (i=0;i<255;i++){
    arr[i]=false;
}
function check(){
    for (i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if (arr[str[i].charCodeAt(0)]==true){
            return false;
        }
        arr[str[i].charCodeAt(0)]=true;
    }
    console.log(arr);
    return true;
}
check();
```

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity = O(n)
Space complexity = O(n)

```
const isUnique = (str) => {
      let charCount = {};
      for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if(charCount[str[i]]){
          return false;
        }

        charCount[str[i]] = true;
      }

      return true;
    }


    const isUniqueCheekyVersion = (str) => {
      return new Set(str).size === str.length;
    }
```

Solution 3:
    Transform string to chars array, sort them and then loop through them to check the adjacent elements, if there is a match return false else true

Solution 4:
    It's similar to Solution 1 except that we use a Set data structure which is introduced in recent versions of javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
// no additional Data structure is required. we can use naive solution
// Time Complexity:O(n^2)
function isUnique(str) {
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 1 + i; j < str.length; j++) {
      if (str[i] === str[j]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

// if you can use additional Data structure 
// Time Complexity:O(n)
function isUniqueSecondMethos(str) {
  let dup_str = new Set();
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (dup_str.has(str[i])) {
      return false;
    }
    dup_str.add(str[i]);
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(isUniqueSecondMethos('hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object as a mapper

```js
function uniqueCharacterString(inputString) {
  const characterMap = {};

  let areCharactersUnique = true;

  inputString.trim().split("").map((ch)=>{
    if(characterMap[ch]===undefined) {
      characterMap[ch] = 1;
    } else {
      areCharactersUnique = false;
    }
  })
  return areCharactersUnique;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm**

1. First string is `"stack"`
2. String covert to CharArray
3. Use iteration in array `['s','t','a','c','k']`
4. `return beginElement !== nextElement`

**Implement code**

```
function uniqueChars(string){
var charArray = Array.from(string) //convert charArray
  for(var i=0;i<charArray.length;i++){
    return charArray[i] !== charArray[i+1]
  }
}
var string = "stack"
console.log(uniqueChars(string))
```

**Time complexity**

*O(nlogn)*

Answer (score 0):

**Algo**

1. Counting frequency of alphabets. e.g. `'Mozilla'` will returns `Object{ M: 1, o: 1, z: 1, i: 1, l: 2, a: 1 }`. Note that, the **bitwise NOT** operator [(~)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) on `-~undefined` is `1`, `-~1` is `2`, `-~2` is `3` etc.
2. Return `true` when all occurrences appear only **once**.

**Implement code**

```js
var isUnique = (str) => {
  const hash = {};
  for (const key of str) {
    hash[key] = -~hash[key];
  }
  return Object.values(hash).every((t) => t === 1);
};

console.log(isUnique('Mozilla'));
console.log(isUnique('Firefox'));
```

---

Another alternative could be:

```js
var isUnique = (str) => {
  const hash = {};
  for (const i in str) {
    if (hash[str[i]]) return false;
    hash[str[i]] = true;
  }
  return true;
};

console.log(isUnique('Mozilla'));
console.log(isUnique('Firefox'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**To make efficient one, you can use** *simple hash map*

```js
let isUnique = (s) => {
    let ar = [...s];
    let check = {};
    for (let a of ar) {
        if (!check[a]) {
            check[a] = 1;
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}
alert("isUnique : "+isUnique("kailu"));
```

> Time complexity  & Space complexity

**using ES6**

```js
let isUnique = (s)=>{
   return new Set([...s]).size == s.length;
}
console.log("using ES6 : ",isUnique("kailu"));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use split method of string:

```
const checkString = (str) => {
let isUniq = true;

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str.split(str[i]).length > 2) {
    isUniq = false;
    break;
  }
}
return isUniq;
};
console.log(checkString("abcdefgh")); //true
console.log(checkString("aa")); //false
```