# Regular expression to match string composed entirely of unique characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I try write a **regExp** ==> **unique character**

Like that:

```
'mam' => false 2*m
'man' => true all unique
'lull' => false
```

PS. I want regExp, no function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if the characters in a string are all unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207610/checking-if-the-characters-in-a-string-are-all-unique)

Comment: something like `str.split('').some( x => str.indexOf(x) != str.lastIndexOf(x))`

Comment: `!/(.).*\1/.test(string)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just test the string outright for true or false

```js
function isNotDup(str) {
  return str.match(/^(?:(.)(?!.*?\1))+$/) ? true : false;
}

console.log('mam = ' + isNotDup('mam'));
console.log('man = ' + isNotDup('man'));
console.log('lull = '   + isNotDup('lull'));
console.log('112233abcabccba = ' + isNotDup('112233abcabccba'));
```